# How can I tell if a push comes from merge request or common push in gitlab?

Tags: events, merge, request, continuous-integration, gitlab

I define rules in.gitlab-ci.yml to filter different events. such as

```
merge_request_check_job:
  script:
    echo "merge request event"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: always
      allow_failure: false
```

```
merge_request_check_job:
  script:
    echo "push event"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      when: always
      allow_failure: false
```

In GitLab CI, a push event can be triggered either by a normal code submission or by a push triggered by clicking the Merge button under the Merge Request menu. How can i tell the difference between these two.

Comment: what do you mean how you can "tell the difference"? Where? The type of pipeline could tell you that, the commits page may be able to tell you depending on what kind of merge strategy you use. Do you mean you want different jobs to run depending on how it's merged?